# Can I Populate a Databound DataGrid with bogus empty rows in a WPF Application?

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0

I was wondering if there is a cohesive trick to populate a DataGrid in a WPF Application with some empty rows so the user can leave some rows empty and fill some others following to them?? my DataGrid is Databound to a CollectionViewSource

Answer (score 0):

Create some dummy rows in the Source collection referenced by the CollectionViewSource.